# git add files to an orphan branch without parent directory

Tags: git

I am trying to push files for a Jekyll docs site into an orphan branch that will be maintained separately from the master:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

I've added the file to a /site directory and from there I am trying to add those to my orphan branch:

```
git add site/ *
```

When I do that it adds all of the files and subdirectories to gh-pages/site, instead of gh-pages. Is there a way to submit all the contents of parent site to gh-pages without adding the parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the orphan branch I needed to:

```
git rm -rf .
```

instead of:

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

then add my updated files and:

```
git push remote <orphan-branch-name>
```

This is surely a duplicate answer, however, I wanted to post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to place the files into the repo root, not under `site/`.

The branch already is a "logical" folder, in a way.

If you want you can always checkout a second branch in another working tree, so you can have both branches checked out simultaneously.

Comment: Understood. However if I do it that way I still have to add individual files and subdirectories on a case-by-case basis. My hope was to be able to do something like git add site/ * and add recursively without the parent appended.

Comment: Nothing. But I wanted add all files and subs from a directory into a branch without adding the parent route